# (Trello.js) Returning ID after getting response in function

Tags: javascript, trello

I've got a function in my code called 'AddNewCard', and in it is

```
Trello.card.create(data).then(response =>{
   console.log(`Card successfully added! ${response.id}`);
   return response.id;
})
```

but whenever the function runs it always returns 'undefined'?

Comment: Please add more scope to the question. Add the library you use and the full code . So, someone will be able to help you

Comment: Can you console.log the entire `response` value to check the `id` is in there?

Comment: I've checked before and the id is definitely there, the first console.log includes it in the message.

Also this is using trello.js

Comment: It's inside [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). `return` is meaningless.